# R flipping coins-stuck on part

Tags: r

Real newbie at R here. I apologize if this question is too obvious to some. I am turning to the online community because no one knows R where I work.

Question: One thousand fair coins. Flip each coin 10 times independently. Let c_1, c_rand, c_min be the number of heads in the first coin flipped, a random coin and the coin that had the minimum frequency of heads (pick earlier one in case of tie). So far I succeeded in writing the code that does the experiment. I want to now pull out the first coin, a random coin and the coin with the last amount of heads from the given sequence but Im lost. Would love to get some direction on this.

```
 i<-1

while(i<=10){
    x<-1
    heads<-0
    tails<-0

    while(x<=10){
        s<-sample(0:1,1)

        if(s==1) heads=heads+1
        else tails=tails+1
        x=x+1}
    cat("heads: ", heads)
    i=i+1}
```

Comment: You want `sample` for sampling from a binomial distribution (and others).  see `?sample`

Comment: You might start with `rbinom(1000, 10, 0.5)`

Comment: If you have a specific problem you can ask it, but don't ask people to write code for you.

Comment: thank you. im gonna try to frame my questions better just really new to the stackoverflow community.

Answer (score 0):

First: the results of 1000 fair coins flipped ten times is the same as one coin flipped 10,000 times with the results recorded in groups of ten.

```
 coins <- matrix( rbinom( 10000, 1, .5), ncol=10)
 coins <- cbind( coins, c_1 = apply( coins, 1, sum) )  # number of heads
```

At this point you natural language description becomes too vague for me to understand what is being attempted. What is a random coin? Do you just want a row number that is `sample(1:1000, 1)`? And with this number of trials I would expect that `which.min( coins[, 'c_1']` will give you the row number of the first all tails row. (it was 119 in my instance.)

Comment: random coin= one of the thousand coins flipped randomly